# Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.NoConstructorsFoundException while injecting dependencies on Asp.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac

I'd like to use autofac to inject dependencies like this:

Startup.cs

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddAuthorization(options => { options.AddPolicy("Enabled", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new UserEnableRequirement())); });
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserEnableHandler>();
        }

        public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterModule<DependencyInjectionModule>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsEnvironment("Local"))
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }


            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseFileServer();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Program.cs

```
 Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
  .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
  {
      webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
  });
```

DependencyInjectionModule.cs

```
 public class DependencyInjectionModule : Module
        {
            protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
            {
builder.RegisterModule<DAL.DependencyInjectionModule>();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            }
        }
```

DAL.DependencyInjectionModule.cs

```
 public class DependencyInjectionModule : Module
        {
            protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
            {
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(ThisAssembly).Where(t => t.Namespace == "DAL.Repositories").AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            }
        }
```

But when I boot it, returns a strange error:

Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.NoConstructorsFoundException: 'No accessible constructors were found for the type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.CacheEntry'.'

If I add this command:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMemoryCache, MemoryCache>();
```

it returns the same error, but pointing at another native type

Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.NoConstructorsFoundException: 'No accessible constructors were found for the type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.BCryptGenRandomImpl'.'

I don't know what I am missing. As this error is not about my packages, how can I bypass it, without writing useless instructions as above?

UPDATE @JohanP

```
public class UserEnableRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
     ....
    }

    public class UserEnableHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UserEnableRequirement>{...
```

Comment: How does your `UserEnableHandler` constructor look?

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

You are trying to register *literally every type in the whole system* with Autofac. That includes all the ASP.NET Core assemblies and everything. That includes the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.BCryptGenRandomImpl` type from an assembly you don't own.

Basically, *dont' do that*.

Be selective about what you register. Assembly scanning is for stuff like "I have a bunch of handlers *in my assembly* or in *a set of assemblies I control* and I want to register them all." It's not for "register everything in the system."

- Be picky about your assemblies.
- Filter down to just types you actually want to resolve.

```cs
// Maybe only use the application assembly?
var assembly = typeof(Startup).Assembly;

// Only register stuff you need to, maybe some handlers
// or something. Note ASP.NET Core already handles
// registering controllers when you do
// services.AddControllersWithViews() so there's
// no value in registering those again.
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
       .Where(t => t.Name.Contains("Handler"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces();

// You can do this multiple times, you don't have to
// filter everything and register all in one go.
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
       .Where(t => t.Name.Contains("Repository"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: Nice info. However, I've got a Repository package in a different library, I updated the question. Also, as for "Handler", should I remove AddSingleton?

Comment: Look at the pattern rather than the literal "here's the exact code." The point is that you need to manually point at whatever specific assemblies you actually need to register and only register the specific types you need. Don't grab the whole AppDomain. Don't register every type in a whole assembly. That `DependencyInjectionModule` is what is hosing you. _LIterally exactly_ what code you need is so very app-dependent there's no way I could just "give it to you." You're going to need to intelligently apply the pattern.